# Exporting FCS files from GatingSet

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to gate a `flowSet`, take the `gateSet`, and then export it to separate FCS files, which should have only the data I chose to gate. My commands are as follows:

Read the FCS files with the names i want

```
s <- read.flowSet(path = path,files = secondary_datasets,
                  transformation = FALSE, sep="\t")
```

Apply the gating with a custom matrix (mat) i have created in the parent my user gives previously as input

```
gs <- GatingSet(fs)
bf <- rectangleGate(filterId=id, .gate=mat)
add(gs, bf, parent=parent)
recompute(gs)
```

Then try to export the new FCS files

```
write.flowSet(gs@data,outdir = path,"test")
```

The problem is my newly created FCS files (1_test, 2_test) are the same with the pre-gated ones. I can see that the files in the `flowSet` are being loaded properly and the gating gives me no errors, so I guess it works properly as well, since it is a couple lines of code. What am I missing? Doesn't the `gs@data` give me the gated `flowSet`? How can I get it if not?

Sorry if I didn't make my problem clear enough, I'm not a biologist.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to answer without actual data set, which I understand. In general, I would make sure to go through the worked example(s) in the R/Bioconductor flow package, paying special attention on the differences between the example data set and your data set or data object (in R). Good luck.